# Drupal 6 settings table prefixes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, civicrm

I need to merge two versions of a site that was forked and changes have been made to both.

I have managed to get all the content, fields, nodes, views etc in the database. However they do not all display.

One of the versions uses civicrm which is installed in a separate database. For it to work it had a default db prefix.

This is causing some of the data not to load since the tables are getting the prefixes. If I remove the prefixes than civicrm does not load.

I figured I could use different settings for civicm and use he default for the rest. On my localhost environment I can not get this to work due to how drupal loads the settings.

I did a hotfix to drupal to test out my idea by changing line 327 to `$uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` it originaly used `script_name`

That correctly gets the config files to load and my site content is showing! but I can't access civicm even though im logged in to the main site.

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM's civicrm.settings.php (in the same place as settings.php) has information on how to connect to the Drupal database as well as the CiviCRM database (which may or may not be the same). You should
1. Confirm there is a civicrm.settings.php file in the same spot as your settings.php (sites/default or equivalent)
2. Check within civicrm.settings.php that both database entries are correct, the paths to CiviCRM files are correct, and the URL is correct.
3. Clear everything out of sites/default/files/templates_c (cached templates)

Comment: It is set up as a different database and I cleared the cache. I managed to find a solution about 30 min ago to share my user data between the civiCRM section and the rest of the site.